# Duplicate activity to launch many instances of same activity using unique identifier

Tags: android, android-activity, oncreate

I am building a chat client and chatting with every user opens same activity ChatActivity passing an username as intent extras like this one.

```
Intent.putExtra("user", username);
```

Where username being the one one you are chatting with. After extras are sent, ChatAcitivity opens up, handles the extra's username and work accordingly. Now, if i am chatting with multiple users at once, say user1 and user2, each time the activity restarts to handle the data. How can i preserve the chat with both the user and open up the already initialized activity so as to reduce load both to the server & user.

I want something to identify the intent that needs to be opened like chatting with user1 brings user1 ChatActivity to the front and so i can use:

```
resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_USER1ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT_);
```

or something to call that up.

How can i do that??

Comment: I prefer using fragments over activities for this use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you want to have 'duplicate' instances of the ChatActivity, one for each user. You can use the [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT) flag, the document being a conversation with a specific user :

```
    // the URI is used as a document ID
    // a stack / activity with the same id will be reused
    // and the intent passed to onNewIntent()
    // otherwise a new activity is created
    startIntent.setData(Uri.parse("http://my.domain.net/users/" + username));
    startIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT);
```

Please note that each conversation will have its own entry in the Recents screen (Overview screen). This may or may not be what you want.